# Can't Launch Ubuntu One

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one

Could not launch 'Ubuntu One'
Just upgraded from 10.04-->10.10 64-bit. When I try to launch Ubuntu One, I get a dialog that says:

> Could Not Launch 'Ubuntu One"
>   Failed to execute child process "ubuntuone" (No such file or directory)

I uninstalled, and reinstalled. I also followed a process outlined here to completely purge. Still doesn't work.

Not sure how to trouble shoot this...

I have logged in via the website and added my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you're launching it from, but there has never been (to the best of my knowledge) a program called `ubuntuone`. Running `ubuntuone-preferences` (which is available in 10.10 in `System › Preferences › Ubuntu One` should bring up the old preferences application,

[image: Maverick's Ubuntu One Preferences application]

which should start everything running; if this is the first time you're running Ubuntu One on the computer, this should in turn pull up the Ubuntu Single Sign On application,

[image: the Ubuntu Single Sign On client]

Lastly should ensure that `ubuntuone-launch` (visible under the user-friendly name of "Ubuntu One") is listed and enabled amongst the `System › Preferences › Startup Applications`:

[image: Startup Applications Preferences]

Comment: Thanks... this totally helps. What was confusing to me is that I had an item in my Applications/System menu called Ubuntu One. This is probably a leftover from upgrades from prior versions of Ubuntu. Also, in looking at my startup, I discovered that there was no Ubuntu One instance... also, in looking at another machine, the correct command at startup is: /bin/sh -c '[ -d "$HOME/Ubuntu One" ] && ubuntuone-launch'

Comment: whoops, fixed the `u1launch` vs `ubuntuone-launch` thing. The bit before `ubuntuone-launch` is to avoid running even that if the user has never used the service.